# Getting 'Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted' in a very simple react exercise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render

Although there are many posts on this question, none of them really helped me. I am starting to learn React and have a very simple code that isn't working for some reason.

The error happens when I am trying to call the *this.setState()* function inside of a react component that is inserted into an array. I imagined that this could be happening because the component is inside of an array, but I render it afterwards, so it doesn't make a lot of sense for me for that error to be thrown.

I am just trying to change the color of a div when the mouse is over it, by changing its state, which would change the class from "monsterEntry row" to "monsterEntry row toggleGrey". I have a simple css with

```
.toggleGrey{
background-color:grey;
}
```

Also, I have used create-react-app to start working on this. I appreciate any help I can get!
Here is my code:

**Bestiary.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class Bestiary extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            mouseIn: false //the state I want to change.
        }
        this.monsterlist = Object.values(props)[0];
        this.bestiarycomponents = [];
        this.monsterlist.forEach((value, index)=>{
           this.bestiarycomponents.push((
                <div key={index} className={this.state.mouseIn ? "monsterEntry row toggleGrey" : "monsterEntry row"} onMouseOver={this.setState({mouseIn: true})}> //Here is my problem.
                    <span className='monsterEntry-name col-6'>{value.name}</span>
                    <span className='monsterEntry-cr col-2'>{cr}</span>
                    <span className='monsterEntry-source col-4'>{value.source}</span>
                </div>
            ))
        });
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className='bestiary-container'>
                <div className="bestiary-label row">
                        <div className='col-6'>Creature</div>
                        <div className='col-2'>CR</div>
                        <div className='col-4'>Sourcebook</div>
                    </div>
                <div className="bestiary">
                    {this.bestiarycomponents} //here is where I render it.
                    <div><h2>Entries: {this.bestiarycomponents.length}</h2></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Bestiary;
```

I imagine the problem is in my Bestiary.js, but I'll also provide the index.js just in case.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Bestiary from './bestiary';

let httprequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httprequest.responseType = 'json';
httprequest.onreadystatechange = ()=>{
  if(httprequest.readyState === httprequest.DONE){
    if(httprequest.status === 200) {
      ReactDOM.render(<Bestiary bestiary={httprequest.response.monster}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
    }
  }
}
httprequest.open("GET", 'a json api', true)
httprequest.send();
```

The error gets thrown and the color does not change, also, but the rest works fine. The divs and everything else get rendered normally and I have also inspected the page and everything seems to be in order.

What I have tried:

1. Taking the render in the index.js out of a callback, and just putting some example object in place of the json response. Didn't work.
2. Using this.state={mouseIn : true} directly. Didn't work also.
3. Redoing everything, reinstalling node, none of that worked.

I have been searching for solutions for a long time now, I really appreciate any help I can get!!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
onMouseOver={this.setState({mouseIn: true})}
```

To

```
onMouseOver={() => this.setState({mouseIn: true})}
```

The way you wrote it it is being called right away vs. the correct way is to pass `setState` to a function.

Comment: Thanks so much! It actually stopped throwing the error, but the desired effect is still not happening. Nothing changes on the page when I hover the mouse over the divs. Any ideas why?

Comment: Glad that helped, not sure why it isn't updating for you, it works for me when I copied the code on my app.